# Golang GIN. Не может загрузить module scripts

Tags: golang, golang-gin

У меня есть пару js файлов, которые связаны с собой через **export, import**. Все данные файлы находятся в папке js. Вот дерево проекта:

```
.
├── conf
│   ├── config.go
│   ├── config.json
│   └── types.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── ico
│   └── logo.ico
├── main.go
├── server
│   ├── handlers.go
│   └── server.go
└── ui
    ├── css
    │   ├── index.css
    │   └── index.sass
    ├── index.html
    └── js
        ├── config.js
        ├── generate-item.js
        ├── index.js
        ├── key.js
        ├── request-json.js
        └── update-price.js
```

Ну и естественно я роучу js файлы используя GIN'овский ***router.Static()***:

```
r.Static("/js", "ui/js")
```

Файлы находит, если перейти по урлу `"host:port/js/filename.js"`, то можно увидеть исходный код файла.

Но вот только JS сам нигде не отображается, а в консоле висит ошибка:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

В чем проблема? Как можно её исправить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Необходимо передавать мим тип файла( о чем и говорит ошибка). браузер просто не понимает что вы получили "файл скрипта". в общем случае - требуется указать заголовок. с данным роутером не знаком, но очень подозреваю что достаточно сделать примерно так `r.HEAD('/js','application/x-javascript')`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вторым аргументом в данном методе должен быть обработчик handler, а не строка. Что мне за обработчик ставить, чтобы установить `application/x-javascript`

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит заглянуть в документацию или хотябы воспользоваться поиском по стеку :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109065/golang-gin-gonic-content-type-not-setting-to-application-json-with-c-json
Второй ответ - пример как поставить content type и написать обработчик =)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нужно было в заголовок установить application/x-javascript. Используя gin и пример кода, мне помогло данное решение:

```
func JSHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/x-javascript")
}

r.HEAD("/js", JSHandler)
```